# Django can not access the url specified throwing Not found 404

Tags: python, django

I'm getting Not Found: 404 error when trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes. My server is running and I can access the http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin but not the notes page. The app is registered in INSTALLED_APPS as well as its named Notes. Im using Python 3.9 and Django 4.2.2

Notes\urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('notes/', views.notes_initiator, name='notes'),
]
```

Notes\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def notes_initiator(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the notes index.")
```

Project\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('notes/', include('Notes.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I looked at similar problems with Django Not Found errors but they don't have solution that would work for me.

I want to see the message "Hello, world. You're at the notes index." when accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi can you check at http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/notes.
The url pattern looks incorrect

Comment: Hey that is it, what would be the correct pattern though and where should I change it?

Comment: so in Django Project/urls.py you have written path as `notes` and thus all links included must start with .localhost:8000/notes/<path in Notes/urls.py>

Answer (score 0):

To see the message at http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/. Update the code in Project\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('Notes.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```